# Downloading tab delimited file from internet

Tags: r, csv

Does anyone know hot to download the below file into a dataframe in R please?

[Link](https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/dwrc/search/dwAQList.csv)

Have tried the below and it does not seem to work.

```
abc = read.table(url,skip = 7,sep="\t",fileEncoding = "UTF-16")
```

Comment: You need to `download.file` then `read.table` it. Your attempt assumes content is on a webpage.

Comment: You were doing it right. All you need to do is, add a parameter  `fill = T`. or skip the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out already in the comments the problem is in the last line of the file which is'curropted' in a sense:
[image]

So you can eigther use:

```
abc = read.table(url,skip = 7,sep="\t",fileEncoding = "UTF-16",fill=TRUE)
abc <- abc[-nrow(abc),]
```

or

```
abc = read.table(url,skip = 7,sep="\t",fileEncoding = "UTF-16",nrow = 2172)
```

if the size of this file is asssumed to be constant

Final Sollution:
Since the header does contain one element less than the rows below the first colum is taken as row index.Therefore you can set header to FASLE and skip one additional line like this:

```
abc <- read.table(url,skip = 8,sep="\t",fileEncoding = "UTF-16",nrow = 2172,header=FALSE)
```

afterwards you can rename the colums:

```
colnames(abc) <- c("Index","Warrant.code","Warrant.name","Issuer","Underlying.code","Call...Put","Maturity.date","Strike.currency","Strike.price...level")
head(abc)
```

Comment: Thanks. tested both out. The first column however, became the index so all the column titles then became wrong. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. When I run it, the columns get moved by one column. I think it is because it thinks the "Warrant Code" column is an index when it is actually a series of warrant codes?

Comment: I'm still not sure what the result is? Do you get an error message when running the command or is the result different from what you want. If the later is the case it would be helpful if you could post a screen shot or something...

Comment: Ah ok, I got what you want....  `abc <- read.table(url,skip = 8,sep="\t",fileEncoding = "UTF-16",nrow = 2172,header=FALSE)
` and rename the columns afterwards. Point is that in case the header contains one less element than the rows below, the first column is automatically taken as row index. See edit of the answer...

Comment: Thanks! I got around it by bringing the folumn into the dataframe and then just renaming all the columns.

I added the below and just renamed the columns and recreated the index (not that I needed it but I am a little OCD...).
test = cbind(rownames(abc),abc)